# $geoWithin not returning anything

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to use $geoWithin and $centerSpehere to return a list of items within a radius, but no luck.

This is my item's schema:

```
var ItemSchema   = new Schema({
    type : String,
    coordinates : []
});

ItemSchema.index({coordinates: '2dsphere'});
```

This is my database item that I should be seeing:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "552fae4c13f82d0000000002"
},
"type": "Point",
"coordinates": [
    6.7786656,
    51.2116958
],
"__v": 0
}
```

This is running on the server currently just to test, the coordinates seen here will eventually be variable.

```
Item.find( {        
    coordinates: { $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [ [ 51, 6 ], 100/6378.1 ] } }
}, function(err, items) {
    console.log(items); // undefined 
});
```

Items are always undefined, even though that coordinate is within 100Km from the other coordinate.

I get no errors in the console.

Any ideas of what's happening? Is the schema wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The format's wrong. The GeoJSON needs to live under one field:

```
{
    "location" : {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [6.7786656, 51.2116958]
    }
}
```

See e.g. [create a 2dsphere index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/build-a-2dsphere-index/).